# Touch Drawing in UITABLEVIEWCELL ios 7

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, drawing

I have a `UIView` in `UITableViewCell` which i can draw lines with my fingers.  This cell is being used for getting signatures from user. But it's acting strange. When i try to draw in this view, i have to touch this view and keep it there like 0.5 second to activate drawing.

I think this is related with drawing in `UIScrollView` (which is `UITableView`). Is there any way to understand this touch event and disable this scrolling feature on `UITableView`, if the user touch this signature view.Thanks

Comment: Why not push or present a different view when the user selects to edit a signature?

Comment: Actually, it is my plan B, but i want it to be more user friendly. And i thought that this look better.

Comment: More user friendly means interacting in a predictable way. If a user is scrolling and happens to try scrolling from that cell then the scroll wouldn't work and a line would be drawn instead. It would also be easy to inadvertently draw over the signature. I'd make it read only unless explicitly requested, and then disable scroll. Though this is really a UX question and should be aimed at the appropriate stack exchange site...

Comment: It is requested by our customer but we will change this functionality . Thank you